# oci_connect() works only from command line

Tags: php, oracle10g, suse, apache2.2, oci8

OK, so I have this terrible problem with oci, apache, php and suse. First off, versions:

```
PHP 5.3.15 (cli)
Apache/2.2.22 (Linux/SUSE)
OCI8 1.4.9
SUSE 12.2 32 bit
Oracle client 10.2.0.4
```

### Problem

I have really simple php file:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    oci_connect('user', 'passwd', 'host/sid');
?>
```

When I run it from command line it executes fine:

```
machine:~ # php oci.php
machine:~ #
```

But when i run it in browser, it gives me:

```
Warning: oci_connect() [function.oci-connect]: OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH are set and point to the right directories
```

### Apache configuration

I've been struggling with this issue for some time now and I'm pretty sure my apache configuration is correct.

I export all required variables **before** any apache process is started - I added

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/oracle/home/lib; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ORACLE_HOME=/path/to/oracle/home; export ORACLE_HOME
TNS_ADMIN=/path/to/oracle/home/network/admin; export TNS_ADMIN
NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.EE8MSWIN1250; export NLS_LANG
```

at the beginning of `/etc/init.d/apache2` script (I start apache by `/etc/init.d/apache2 start`).

Apache runs from `wwwrun` user, who is in `oinstall` and `dba` groups:

```
machine:~ # cat /etc/apache2/uid.conf
User wwwrun
Group www
machine:~ # id wwwrun
uid=30(wwwrun) gid=8(www) groups=8(www),113(oinstall),114(dba)
machine:~ # l $ORACLE_HOME
total 216
drwxr-xr-x 48 oracle oinstall 4096 Jan 25 17:07 ./
drwxrwxr-x  3 oracle oinstall 4096 Jan 25 17:01 ../
...
machine:~ #
```

### Possible problem

I don't have any environmental variables in `Environment` section in `phpinfo();` output - could this be the problem? If yes, how can I fix this? Is it some kind of security issue? I've read about problems like that with SELinux enabled, but I don't have it, my firewall is off.

### Solution?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved! Thanks to [these](http://php.net/oci8.installation) (*Setting the Oracle Environment* section) instructions and ken_yap's answer to [this](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/applications/393416-setting-apache2-environment-variables.html) thread.

To put variables in Apache's *Environment* section you just have to add them in `/etc/sysconfig/apache2` file: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/oracle/lib`.

Comment: in CentOS 7, the file is called `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`

Answer (score 3):

Another solution ( that do not need root access ) is to add this lines in the php page:

```
putenv("ORACLE_HOME=/opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1");
putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/lib:/lib:/usr/lib");
```

Regards

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to add environment variables to runtime code - they can often be ignored because the code is run after process or module initialization

Answer (score 0):

For Debian users - edit file

```
/etc/apache2/envvars
```

on the end of file add link to your OCI library - eg.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach for Centos 7 with `nginx`

```
$ sudo vim /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf

// Add path to oracle client lib, the XX is the version, ex: /usr/lib/oracle/XX/client64/lib 

$ sudo ldconfig
$ sudo service php-fpm restart
```

Done!